# Date / Time problem in javascript with highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, highcharts

2011-09-13 is today (GMT+0)

```
Date.UTC(<%= effort.week_commencing.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") %>)
```

Outputs

```
Date.UTC(2011,09,12)
```

This is right because it is getting the 12Th which is the start of the month.

But in high charts / stock charts it is displaying 1 month ahead "12Th of October"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `new Date().getMonth()`  you will see that it returns 8 instead of 9 (September), this is because in javascript months are zero-based-numbered

Answer (score 3):

Months for `Date` are enumerated from 0. So `Date.UTC(2011,09,12)` is really 12th of October and `Date.UTC(2011,08,12)` will be 12th of September. Just subtract 1 from month value.